# Setting up Googletest in Unix

Tags: g++, googletest

I have problem using GoogleTest, namely is not clear to me what libs (and how) I should include. Following the instructins contained in the `README` I did

```
g++ -isystem ${GTEST_DIR}/include -I${GTEST_DIR} -pthread -c \
${GTEST_DIR}/src/gtest-all.cc
```

and

```
ar -rv libgtest.a gtest-all.o
```

where `${GTEST_DIR}` is the place where the google test folder lives.
After these steps I have a `gtest-all.o` and `libgtest.a` inside `${GTEST_DIR}`

How do I compile my `Test.cpp` file now? I have tried (as suggested in the same instructions)

```
g++ -isystem ${GTEST_DIR}/include -pthread Test.cpp libgtest.a -o test
```

but I obtain the error

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'libgtest.a'
```

even adding

```
-L${GTEST_DIR}
```

doesn't seem to help.
What (and how) should I include in my script?

Bonus question: there is also the possibility to create a folder and do `cmake .. && make` there. This will create (among the CMake files) the lib `libgtest.a` and `libgtest_main.a`. How are this different? Was it done for compatibility reasons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
g++ -isystem ${GTEST_DIR}/include -L${GTEST_DIR} -lgtest -pthread Test.cpp -o test
```

As for the multiplicity of ways to build gtest, here's a relevant section of the README:

```
Before settling on CMake, we have been providing hand-maintained build
projects/scripts for Visual Studio, Xcode, and Autotools.  While we
continue to provide them for convenience, they are not actively
maintained any more.  We highly recommend that you follow the
instructions in the previous two sections to integrate Google Test
with your existing build system.
```

The key takeaway here is that for very small projects you can either compile everything by hand as you've done or use cmake; it just depends on what you're comfortable with. For large projects you should integrate into your own build system.